# how to plot customized JSON data on c3js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, c3.js

I want to plot C3js pie chart based on the following JSON (received from HQL-hibernate Java Play framework)...
JSON looks like this (This is dynamic data):

```
{"ug":["K","M2","M3","M4"],"wtv":[10,20,35,60]}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS (what I actually tried):

```
var json ={"ug":["K","M2","M3","M4"],"wtv":[10,20,35,60]};
var ug =json.ug;
var wtv=json.wtv;     
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
       json: {
          ug:wtv[0],
          ug1:wtv[1],
          ug2:wtv[2],
          ug3:wtv[3],
        },
        type : 'pie',
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle for reference.](https://jsfiddle.net/x68625gw/)

In places of ug,ug1,ug2,ug3 I need K,M2,M3,M4(To be noted these are dynamic data)
Can anyone help me to manipulate the data to draw the pie chart as required?
I hope changing the structure of JSON at the back end is not the only solution (it is very difficult in my case though). Any other solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so long as `"ug"` and `"wtv"` have the same number of elements...

```
var json = {"ug":["K","M2","M3","M4"],"wtv":[10,20,35,60]};
var pieJson = {};
json.ug.forEach(function (ug, index) {
  pieJson[ug] = json.wtv[index];
});

var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    // iris data from R
    json: pieJson,
    type : 'pie',
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/4h4z00g7/](https://jsfiddle.net/4h4z00g7/)

Comment: it did indeed. Thanks for your time and help :)